# Почему у select и input разная высота и как это исправить?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Здесь два вопроса, но из первого вытекает второй.

Почему у `select` и `input` разная высота?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

select,
input[type="text"] {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<select>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<input type="text" value="Test" />
```

И как это исправить чтобы это было гибко?

### Нюансы

Пытаюсь установить для `select` и `input` одинаковую высоту, но очень хочется это сделать гибко, а это значит, что не хочу просто установить фиксированную высоту. Чтобы я менял без проблем `font-size` без необходимости менять высоту. И я не совсем понимаю почему у них получается разная высота ввиду того, что у них одинаковый размер шрифта и одинаковые `padding`, `border` и `box-sizing`.

Ещё понимаю, что можно подобрать разные `padding` для `input` и `select`, но хочется понять механику и причины данных результатов, а также решить их "без хаков".

Из браузеров больше всего любопытен Chrome, но кроссбраузерное решение будет вообще идеальным.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это не во всех браузерах. Разная высота- это одна из особенностей стилизации определённого браузера.

Что бы `select` имел такую же высоту, нужно убрать у него стрелку справа. Но тут нюанс: если мы добавим стрелку текстовому полю, то оно высоту не изменит. так что утверждать на 100%, что это из за стрелки нельзя, но это одно из решений.

Для данного случая можно применить 3 варианта решения:

**Вариант 1:**

Добавление фоновой картинки вместо стандартной стрелки

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

select,
input[type="text"] {
  width: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 13px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
select {
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-image: url(http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/2013/8/426/w32h321377581133134TriangleDown.png);
    background-size: 16%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: center;
    background-position-x: calc(100% - 5px);
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<input type="text" />
```

**Вариант 2:**

Обрамление `select'а` в `div` и добавление псевдокласса `:after`

За основу взят ответ со *eng stackoverflow*: [css-change-dropdown-arrow-to-unicode-triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31531865/css-change-dropdown-arrow-to-unicode-triangle)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

select,
input[type="text"] {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 13px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
select {padding-right: 10px;}
.select {display: inline-block; position: relative;}
.select:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    content: '▼';
    font-size: 0.6rem;
    top: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="select">
  <select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>

<input type="text" value="Test" />
```

**Вариант 3:**

Это вариант схожий с *Вариантом 2*, но здесь мы вместо `:after` используем `svg`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

select,
input[type="text"] {
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 13px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
select {padding-right: 10px;}
.select {display: inline-block; position: relative;}
.select svg {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    width:20px;height:20px;
    font-size: 0.6rem;
    top: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="select">
  <select>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
  <svg width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 15 15">
    <path d="M 8,5.5 11,9.5 14,5.5 z"></path>
  </svg>
</div>

<input type="text" value="Test" />
```

Данные способы также решат проблему того, что `select` отрисовывается по разному в разных браузерах и ОС.

Comment: Мне совсем не хочется убирать стрелку у `select`.

Answer (score 1):

Если присмотреться, то в стандартных стилях у инпута для бордера есть значения `border-style: inset` и `border-width: 2px`. Потому, меняя значение ширины инпуту на 1 пиксель мы вмешиваемся в размер его коробки. Чтобы этого избежать, можно сделать границу однопиксельной и прозрачной, а её вид для инпута сымитировать при помощи `box-shadow`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

select,
input[type="text"] {
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<select>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<input type="text" value="Test" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй вот так

```
select, input[type="text"] {
   padding: 2px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   font-size: 13px;
   min-height: 23px;
}
```

Comment: Смотрите. Даже если мы закроем глаза на то, что здесь ничего не рассказывается о причинах (которые мне тоже интересны), тут ещё это не будет работать, если установить `font-size` другой, скажем `15px`. А у меня в ответе сказано про гибкость. И откуда вы взяли цифру `23px`? Почему не 22 или 24?

Comment: Кстати можно просто установить `height` или поиграться с `padding`, но мне хочется просто меняя `font-size` получать одинаковые высоты `select` и `input`.